# How do I find the filepath to an image in the drawable folder as a string?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I want to find the file path to an image stored in `res/drawable/` in a format that is easy to parse. For example, `drawable://2131099733` is bad to parse, but `/drawable/1.jpg` is easy. What I've tried below doesn't work, but that would be the ideal way to do it.

The reason why I want it is because I will have images that are named things like `1.jpg` and `2.jpg`, then I will be able to use string concatenation to easily load it into an `ImageView`.

```
File imgFile = new File("/res/drawable/adorable-animal-cat-20787.jpg");
```

Comment: Resource drawables don't exist as files on the device. They are only files on your development machine. If you want to load a drawable by its name, the answers on the linked duplicate have examples of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (using the `File` class) will never work because at runtime the drawables are packaged in the APK.

Now, to load a drawable into an `ImageView` at runtime (from code) simply do the following:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drawable_resource_identifier);
```

However, you need to load the drawables from a String value you can use the `Resources` class to resolve the identifier of the drawable...

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(resID);
```

Comment: Please just vote it as a duplicate, rather than editing your answer to include the solution I've already linked.

Comment: The solution in the duplicate works like a charm, thanks!